# non_form_errors doesn't show

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am working with `inlineformset_factory` and created a `forms.BaseInlineFormSet` to override the `clean` function to make some validations. the validation works and the form isn't accepted but the `ValidationError` message doesn't appear when the page is reloaded.

here is my form class:

```
class BaseDetailFormSet(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        super(BaseDetailFormSet, self).clean()
        if any(self.errors):
            return self.errors

        for form in self.forms:
            product = form.cleaned_data['product']
            if form.cleaned_data['quantity_sold'] > product.quantity_in_stock:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_('not enough products'))


DetailFormset = inlineformset_factory(Invoices,
                                      InvoiceDetail,
                                      fields=('product', 'quantity_sold'),
                                      widgets= {'product': forms.Select(
                                        attrs={
                                            'class': 'search',
                                            'data-live-search': 'true'
                                        })},
                                      formset=BaseDetailFormSet,
                                      extra=1)
```

and my `html` code:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="">
                    {% csrf_token%}
                    {% include '_layouts/form_snippet.html' %}
                    <table class="table">
                        {{inlines.management_form}}
                        {%for form in inlines.forms%}
                            {% if forloop.first%}
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    {%for field in form.visible_fields%}
                                    <th>{{field.label|capfirst}}</th>
                                    {%endfor%}
                            {%endif%}
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                        <tr class="formset_row">
                                    {{ form.non_form_errors }}

                                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                                        <td>
                                            {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                                            {% if forloop.first %}
                                                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                                    {{ hidden }}
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                            {{ field }}
                                        </td>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                    </table>

                        <button type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-inverse">{% trans 'Submit Invoice' %}</button>

                </form>
```

any ideas how to show the validation error message or why it isn't shown.

Comment: Note that you're not handling the case where I select the same product multiple times in the formset, and the total `quantity_sold` is more than `product.quantity_in_stock`.

Answer (score 2):

`non_form_errors` belongs to the *formset* not the form.

So you can display it with:

```
{{ formset.non_form_errors }}
```

Or in your case, since you use the variable `inlines`:

```
{{ inlines.non_form_errors }}
```

Since it belongs to the formset, you should do this *outside* of the forloop through the forms.

If you have errors on the form that don't belong to any field, then you access these with

```
{{ form.non_field_errors }}
```

Comment: it didn't work, where should i put it exactly, in the same place of `{{form.non_form_errors}}?

Comment: Make sure you didn't miss out the `s` in `non_form_errors` like I did. Put it *outside* of the for loop, as I said. If you put it in the same place, then you'll show the same errors for every single form.

Comment: This is the **correct answer**. Why has it not been marked as such?